# Convert String into dateTime

Tags: java, date, datetime, simpledateformat

I have a problem with convert string to date as follow

```
public void main(String[] args) {<br>
String s1 = "2013-03-18 00:30:00 +0200";<br>
String s2 = "2013-03-18 12:30:00 +0200";<br>
<br>
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzzz");<br>
<br>

Date date1 = sdf.parse(s1);<br>
Date date2 = sdf.parse(s2);<br>
<br>
System.out.println((date2.getTime()-date1.getTime()) );<br>

always i obtient zero beacause it convert 12h to 00. <br>
<br>
```

Thank you.

Comment: I just copied this code directly into a class and it executed with the expected result of `43200000`

Comment: You could parse integers from the string then use those to set the parts of the dates you need one by one utilizing the Calendar.set(x, y) method. But as the one of the comments above me said that should work as you expect.

Comment: @Andremoniy Did you mean to vote-to-close a java question as dupe of a python question?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure but shouldn't it be like this?

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z");
```

Reference:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

**Edit:** Now I'm quite sure about it

```
z   Time zone   General time zone   Pacific Standard Time; PST; GMT-08:00

Z   Time zone   RFC 822 time zone   -0800
```

Comment: I resolved this problem.<br>
in fact this code is alright. I was used hh instead of HH<br>
hh is a  Hour in am/pm (1-12) and <br>
HH is a Hour in day (0-23) 
<br>
<br>

thank you.